# (RedOx) How should i continue?

Tags: redox

i'm stuck on a redox, currently in the oxidation semireaction. The reaction is:

$\ce{B + NaOH = NaBO2 + H2 + Na2O}$

The reduction semi reaction is: $\ce{B = NaBO2}$

And i balanced it like this: $\ce{B + NaOH + H2O + 3e- = NaBO2 + 3H+}$

Problem is the oxidation semi reaction, i start with: $\ce{NaOH = H2}$

and balance it like: $\ce{2NaOH + 2H+ = H2 + Na2O + H2O + 2e-}$

Problem is that when i add everything up after balancing electrons and stuff (Multiply 3 with the oxidation semireaction and 2 with the reduction semireaction) Na won't be balanced. Plus, on a redox solver online, instead of balancing $\ce{NaOH = H2}$ he starts with $\ce{H2O}$, why is that?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I would start with H2O as well. But if you are positively certain that H2O is not there, then balance your second half-reaction without H2O on the right and without H+ on the left.

Comment: No H2O is mentioned in the text. Why should i start with H2O instead of NaOH?

Comment: Because we live in the world dominated by H2O. Well, if the products were specified this way, with Na2O and stuff, then probably they really mean the absence of H2O, so go with the second option.

Comment: Isn't the reaction supposed to be balanced in basic medium?

Comment: Problem is, they don't tell you if it's in acid or basic medium.. when i balance it with what i've done, the answer isn't right.. it has to do with that NaOH

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the emphasis on redox. True that the boron is oxidized, but the conditions are so unrealistic that I can't figure out what issue is being solved here.

The conditions are harsh: Na2O in the product means fused salt, so you are starting with molten NaOH, adding boron and getting H2 + NaBO2 and Na2O. Actually the molten mass would just appear to be Na3BO3 (sodium orthoborate).

The balanced equation would be 2B + 6 NaOH --> 3 H2 + 2 Na3BO3 
(or --> 3 H2 + 2 NaBO2 + 2 Na2O using the products indicated in the problem).